# Why I cannot use \ or backslash in a String in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have a string like this in below and I want replace space with backslash and space.

```
let test: String = "Hello world".replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "\ ")
print(test)
```

But Xcode make error of :

> Invalid escape sequence in literal

The code in up is working for any other character or words, but does not for backslash. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backslash is used to escape characters. So to print a backslash itself, you need to escape it. Use `\\`.

Comment: or simply `#"\ "#`

Comment: @LeoDabus: You can add it as an answer as well. thanks

Answer (score 2):

For Swift 5 or later you can avoid needing to escape backslashes using the enhanced string delimiters:

```
let backSlashSpace = #"\ "#
```

If you need String interpolation as well:

```
let value = 5
let backSlashSpaceWithValue = #"\\#(value) "#
print(backSlashSpaceWithValue) //  \5
```

You can use as many pound signs as you wish. Just make sure to mach the same amount in you string interpolation:

```
let value = 5
let backSlashSpaceWithValue = ###"\\###(value) "###
print(backSlashSpaceWithValue) //  \5
```

---

Note: If you would like more info about this already implemented Swift evolution proposal SE-0200 [Enhancing String Literals Delimiters to Support Raw Text](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0200-raw-string-escaping.md)